# Error renaming matching files with perl one liner

Tags: regex, perl, unix, file-rename

I want to rename all the files that match a pattern.
This kind of one liners usually work for me, but I'm getting some kind of error.

Kind of file names I have: PMSNpoda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt SCSNpoda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt

File names I want: PM-SN_poda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt SC-SN_poda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt

My first try was:

```
ls *fst.txt | perl -ne '/^([A-Z][A-Z])([A-Z][A-Z])(poda.*?$)/; system("mv $_ $1-$2_$3")'
```

But it didn't work.

Finally I came up with a line that prints exactly what I want

```
ls *fst.txt | perl -lne '/([a-zA-Z]{2})([a-zA-Z]{2})(poda.*?$)/; print "mv $_ $1-$2_$3"'
```

prints:

```
mv PMSNpoda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt PM-SN_poda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt
mv SCSNpoda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt SC-SN_poda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt
```

But when I use it in order to rename the files:

```
ls *fst.txt | perl -lne '/([a-zA-Z]{2})([a-zA-Z]{2})(poda.*?$)/; system("mv $_ $1-$2_$3")'
```

I get

```
sh: $'32mPMSNpoda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt\E[0m': command not found
mv: missing destination file operand after ''$'\033''[01'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
sh: $'32mSCSNpoda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt\E[0m': command not found
mv: missing destination file operand after ''$'\033''[01'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

Again but adding echo

```
ls *fst.txt | perl -lne '/([a-zA-Z]{2})([a-zA-Z]{2})(poda.*?$)/; system("echo mv $_ $1-$2_$3")'
```

I get

```
mv
h: $'32mPMSNpoda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt\E[0m': command not found
mv
h: $'32mSCSNpoda5718_1p2g_out_fst.txt\E[0m': command not found
```

Can someone point me which is the error so I can understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have ANSI colors in the output of `ls`? If so, try to turn off the coloring.

Comment: Yes, filenames are in green, should I delete ```alias ls="ls -p --color"``` from .bash_profile

Comment: Yes that would work, see also [Turn off color in Linux terminal/bash session](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-off-color-in-linux-terminal-bash-session/), or just type `unalias ls`, see [How do I remove an alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325368/how-do-i-remove-an-alias/325380#325380)

Comment: @Mosky At minimum you should switch to `--color=auto`.

Comment: Huh? If you can write Perl, you'd be many times better off using `rename` which uses a Perl expression such as yours but also allows you to do dry-runs and prevents files getting clobbered when names clash. Also known as **Perl rename**.

Comment: Yeah, if you have the perl `rename` program, you can just do `rename '/([a-zA-Z]{2})([a-zA-Z]{2})/$1-$2_/' *fst.txt` (sometimes it's also installed as `prename`). But if you have the `rename` program from `util-linux`, it won't work.

Comment: just changing the alias to ```alias ls="ls -p --color=auto"``` as suggested by @melpomene worked perfectly (also commenting it out as suggested by @Håkon)

Comment: @Mosky From the `ls` man page: "_With `--color=auto`, `ls` emits color codes only when  standard output is connected to a terminal._"  So when you pipe into another program it doesn't add those codes (since then it's not going to a terminal).  There is also `LS_COLORS` environment variable for this, see man page.  Also, try `\ls`, as it should run without the alias -- for that one execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to run the rename via the shell.

```
ls -1 *fst.txt | perl -MFile::Copy=move -wlnE'
    $new = s/([a-zA-Z]{2})([a-zA-Z]{2})/$1-$2_/r; move $_, $new'
```

Note the `-1` option on `ls`, so that you do get one filename per line.

The `32m` and `[0m` are ANSI escapes, that can set colors (and other properties) for the terminal, often used for shell configuration (for prompt for example). Perhaps your `ls` is putting out those and `mv` is getting terribly confused with them? One more example of why it's better to avoid going through the shell, unless necessary of course.

In some shells the existing aliasing, whereby a command is in fact run with various options (which is why `ls` output gets "dressed" with those codes), can be suppressed by prepending the command by the backslash, `\ls`.

Another option is to reduce reliance on the system as much as possible, and build the file list in the program as well

```
perl -MFile::Copy=move -wE'
    for (glob "*fst.txt") { 
        $new = s/([a-zA-Z]{2})([a-zA-Z]{2})/$1-$2_/r;
        move $_, $new or warn "Cant rename $_ to $new: $!" }'
```

where responsibility for building the correct filelist is now on `glob`.

Comment: So why pipe `ls` into `perl`? You can just do `perl -wE 'for (glob "*fst.txt") { $new = s/([a-zA-Z]{2})([a-zA-Z]{2})/$1-$2_/r; rename $_, $new or warn "$_ -> $new: $!\n" }'`.

Comment: @melpomene Right, not necessary.  But I don't see anything wrong with building a file list outside, while it may reduce complexity.   Will add more, thank you for the comment

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a few reasons why `ls | ...` is a bad idea (plus in OP's case it adds color codes). The reason `perl ... *fst.txt` may be an issue is that if there are too many files matching the pattern, the resulting list may exceed the size limit of `argv`.

Comment: @melpomene  My point here is to leave it to OP to build their filelist, not to parse `ls`; _I don't recommend parsing `ls`_. So supposedly they'd submit a good filelist, that is on them.  Moving it into the program then requires the program to ensure that all is well -- which is fine, but it adds to the program. (I'll add that.)

Comment: Thanks guys I'm going to try to rely less on parsing ```ls```. Usually I work in a unix server and there is no problems, but now I'm in a windows computer with cygwin and I got this problem. both codes using ```glob``` work fine!